blender pythonで、blender3.5で正常に動くコードが4.1では期待通りに動かない
前提
下記コードはオブジェクトを複製しつつ複製したオブジェクトのvertex colorを変えることを期待したものです。
「ic」というオブジェクトを選択して実行します。
最終的には数十個のオブジェクトを連続して生成しつつグラデーションに色を変えたく、このコードは
その問題要素部分のみ抜き出しました。
問題
blender3.5では正常に動くが、blender4.1では元オブジェクトまで色が変わってしまう問題があることが分かりました。
4.0以降での仕様変更なのでしょうか、であればどう修正すれば4.1でも正常に動くようになりますか？
import colorsys
import bpy
import random

def duplicate_move_and_rename(obj, x, y, z):
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(x, y, z)})
    return
    

obj = bpy.context.active_object

# -------------------------------------------------
duplicate_move_and_rename(obj, -2, 0, 0)
obj2 = bpy.context.active_object;
vc2 = obj2.data.vertex_colors[0].data
hue = 1.0
print(hue)
saturation = 1.0
value = 1.0
for polygon2 in obj2.data.polygons:
    for i, v in zip(polygon2.loop_indices, polygon2.vertices):
        vc2[i].color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, saturation, value)+(1,)



新たにchatGPT4がフリー解放されたのでblender4.0の仕様変更に対応可能か聞いたところ
以下の回答を得て、上記問題は解決しました。ありがとうございました。
原因は新しいAttributesの仕様変更でした。
import colorsys
import bpy
import random

def duplicate_move_and_rename(obj, x, y, z):
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(x, y, z)})
    return bpy.context.active_object

def change_object_color(obj, hue, saturation, value):
    # 頂点カラー属性を取得または作成
    if 'Col' in obj.data.color_attributes:
        color_attr = obj.data.color_attributes['Col']
    else:
        color_attr = obj.data.color_attributes.new(name='Col', type='FLOAT_COLOR', domain='CORNER')
    
    # 頂点カラーを設定
    for i, loop in enumerate(obj.data.loops):
        color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, saturation, value) + (1,)
        color_attr.data[i].color = color

# アクティブなオブジェクトを取得
obj = bpy.context.active_object

# オブジェクトを複製して色を変更
obj2 = duplicate_move_and_rename(obj, -2, 0, 0)

# 色を変更する
hue = random.random()
saturation = 1.0
value = 1.0
change_object_color(obj2, hue, saturation, value)

